# Passing parameters to a callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript callback functions. I tried the following piece of code:

```
var callbackTester = function(callback) {
  var tryMe = "Are you ready, ";
  callback(tryMe);
}

var createMessageHandler = function(client) {
  this.client = client;
  this.result = function(foo){
    console.log(foo + " "+ this.client);
  }
};

(new createMessageHandler("John")).result(callbackTester);
```

Instead of "Are you ready, Jason", I get the entire callback function displayed followed by name:

```
function (callback) {
  var tryMe = "Are you ready, ";
  callback(tryMe);
} John
```

Can someone help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: So `result` takes a function `foo`, and `foo +` will stringify the function.

Comment: Inside of `this.result` you never actually called `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foo` argument is not a string, it's a callback which you need to call. One of the possible solutions is:

```
var callbackTester = function (callback) {
    var tryMe = "Are you ready, ";
    callback(tryMe);
};

var createMessageHandler = function (client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.result = function (foo) {
        foo(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg + " " + this.client);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};

(new createMessageHandler("John")).result(callbackTester);
```

Mind `.bind(this)` - you need to do that in order to preserve `this.client` from the outer scope.

More on the `bind` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Note: I don't quite understand the purpose of your code though. Aren't you getting into a callback hell? Try monads/promises instead.

`new createMessageHandler` isn't intuitive. IMHO it should either be `new MessageHandler()` or just `createMessageHandler()`

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'm just getting started with JS and will look into promises shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a `callbackTester` function, and it takes a callback as argument, so you have to give it a callback, otherwise it will never work. Also, you have to `return` that callback. Otherwise you'll never get anything but the function itself. Here is a solution:

```
var callbackTester = function(callback) {
    var tryMe = "Are you ready,";
    return callback(tryMe);
}

var createMessageHandler = function(client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.result = function(foo){
        console.log(foo + " "+ this.client);
    }
}

(new createMessageHandler("John")).result(callbackTester(function(phrase) { return phrase; }));
// Are you ready, John
```

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm getting a "TypeError: createMessageHandler is not a constructor" error.